# Convert a date from 14 to 2014

Tags: java, date, format

How can I format a :

> Tue May 21 00:00:00:00 GMT +200 14 <---  Tue May 21 00:00:00:00 GMT
>   +200 2014

i tried :

```
 StringBuilder myName = new StringBuilder(datum);
        myName.setCharAt(datum.length()-4, '2');
        myName.setCharAt(datum.length()-3, '0');
                Date date= null;         DateTimeFormat.getFormat("-- idk ----").parse(myName.toString());      Window.alert(myName.toString());
```

but i dont know how to define the same date format as the Date class

i think this isnt a good solution is there a better?

Comment: I didnt know _-- idk ----_ was a format

Comment: I think "idk" => "I don't know" :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that `datum` is a `Date` object.
So, just do:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss:SS z yyyy");
System.out.println(df.format(datum));
```

More info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html.

Answer (score 0):

// getFormatedDate("in which pattern you are sending date", "how we want", date in string form);
             example :   formatedDate = getFormatedDate("yyyy-MM-dd", "ddMMyyyy", "2014-05-21");

```
  private String getFormatedDate(String baseFormat, String reqFormat, String dateStr) {


    String formatedDate = null;

    try {
        DateFormat fromFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(baseFormat);
        fromFormat.setLenient(false);
        DateFormat toFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(reqFormat);
        toFormat.setLenient(false);
        java.util.Date date = fromFormat.parse(dateStr);
        formatedDate = toFormat.format(date);

    } catch (ParseException ex) {

    }
    return formatedDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **date formatter.**

Your date formatter should be

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss:SS z yyyy");
```

Then use this formatter to get your desired date. 
Just do:

```
newDate = dateFormat.format(yourOldDate);
```

Hope this will works.

Get more from:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-date-and-calendar-examples/

and  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to not duplicate answer, since the same exact answer has been already give 10 minutes ago. Just add a +1 to the answer or add edition complementary information on the answer which is already give.